# Why is this integral zero when evaluated across all space?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, integration

I have a problem figuring out why the integral bellow is zero.
(The following is text from the book Classical Theory of Electromagnetism by Baldassare Di Bartolo):

First a general picture of the problem.

We consider the following situaton (general electrostatic problem). We have:
 - A charge distribution with density $\rho$(**x**) 
 - A volume V delimited by a surface S 
 - A point of observation **Xp**

[image: The "situation"]

We do not know what is inside V, but we do know the values that the potential takes on the surface surrounding V. $ \phi $ (**Xp**) is in general different from what it would be if we had only the charge distribution. Green's theorem, in its second form, gives us Eq. (2.9.1)
$$
 \int_{V}^{ } (\psi\Delta \phi -\phi\Delta\psi)d\tau  = \int_{S}^{ } (\psi\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n} - \phi\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial n})dS
$$
$\phi$(**x**) is the potential we try to determine. We note that
$$
\Delta \phi(\boldsymbol{x}) = -4\pi\rho (\boldsymbol{x})
$$
and we let
$$
\psi(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x_{p}}|}
$$
Obviously,
$$
\Delta \psi(\boldsymbol{x}) = -4\pi\delta (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{x_{p}})
$$

**Since $\phi(\infty)=\psi(\infty)=0$, the integral in Eq. (2.9.1) extended to all space is zero,** and the integral extended to "all space minus V" is equal to minus the integral over the volume V..

---

The problem I have is, why is the bolded statement true? in other words why is that integral over all space equal to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of space means the surface integral is at $\infty$. As per your boundary condition in bold, all fields are equal to 0 there, so the RHS and hence the LHS is 0.

Comment: Strictly speaking one also needs to argue that the gradient terms aren't infinite, but that should be obvious - there are no charges at infinity, so the electric field shouldn't be discontinuous there.

Comment: I am sorry, I must be missing something obvious here. Just because the integrand is zero at the boundary, does'nt mean it is zero somewhere close to charge. The way I see it is that would be equivalent to saying that the integral of 1/x^2 from infinity must be zero just because it goes to zero  at infinity.

Comment: @Jure Vreca it’s a surface integral so $\mathbf x$ is evaluated at spatial infinity throughout the whole integration.

Comment: Oh god, I am an idiot. Thanks for the anwser. I kept looking at the LHS and I just could'nt see it.

Comment: Also when I looked at RHS, I thought S was the boundary of V...

Comment: @JureVreča If you understood the answer you should vote it up and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @BorunChowdhury will do.